# Printing a PDF directly from the Web: no print dialog in OSX

Tags: macos, curl

I have a Kiosk app that runs on a **MacMini** that I have inherited.

I need to take a PDF that lives on the web   (Say the URL is http://www.mypdf.com?ID=1234 )

I wish to use the Terminal.app to pull that PDF from the web and send it directly to the currently selected printer **without** a keyboard or mouse so I can't have the Print dialog pop up.

I stink at "Curl".  Can somebody kindly tell me what the command is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  For anyone else looking for the answer:

```
curl http://www.mypdf.com?id=1234 > print.pdf; lpr print.pdf
```

Comment: Suggestion: since `lpr` can read file(s) from stdin, you can just pipe your PDF as follow: `curl -s http://www.mypdf.com?id=1234 | lpr` (note `-s` enables silent mode).